# One Animated.Value vs. Many for Controlling Transitions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, react-animated

When implementing a transition animation that effects many different elements, or many instances of the same Component, is there a best practice regarding where to control the animation?  I have toyed with two different methods but I am not sure which is better.

One option is for the highest-up Component in the tree to create a Animated.Value that serves as a timer going from 0 to 1.  It passes this timer down to descendants as a prop, and the descendants use Value.interpolate to do what they need to with it.  This fits with the React design principle of moving state up, but passing around an Animated.Value as a prop feels odd (though it works fine) and the value always needs to be interpolated to be useful.

The other option is to pass down a boolean prop, like "isTransitioning."  The descendants each hold their own Animated.Value and have a useEffect hook which starts the animation when isTransitioning switches to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion we should refer to SRP here (Single Responsibility Principle - module should have one and only one reason to change) and DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

If in your particular situation descendants are separate components that can be reused somewhere else - this may be a good reason to put this functionality inside. But if this is a single indivisible component - it's better to keep only one `Animated.Value` and apply it to all children.

Optimization, btw, is the last think we should care about, if there are no obvious problems with this. Maintainability is the top priority.